# display an html page within tinymce textarea

Tags: php, html, email, tinymce, textarea

How can I display an HTML page in the tinymce textarea.

```
<?php 

$filename = "template-3.html";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;

?>
```

I have used the above code to display html page. But, It displays only the text contents in textarea and it doesn't display images and positioning of the html page.

What do I need to do in order to display html page like:

http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/hero.html#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code display html preview in textarea field. I don't know whether it is a correct way to implement. But, I've got the result that I wanted.

```
 tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent($('div div#template1').html());
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call and return the html page which you can append anywhere you want.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/hero.html#",
        success:function(result){
        $("#textarea").html(result);
    }});
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry friend. I've tried this code code. But I didn't get the result. I just used jQuery itselft to display html in textarea.